# Is it bad to show errors in Browser console when API call fails?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have the following svelte code to fetch the random number and show on UI:

```
<script>
    let promise = getRandomNumber();

    async function getRandomNumber() {
        const res = await fetch(`tutorial/random-number`);
        const text = await res.text();

        if (res.ok) {
            return text;
        } else {
            throw new Error(text);
        }
    }

    function handleClick() {
        promise = getRandomNumber();
    }
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
    generate random number
</button>

{#await promise}
    <p>...waiting</p>
{:then number}
    <p>The number is {number}</p>
{:catch error}
    <p style="color: red">{error.message}</p>
{/await}
```

I took this code from : https://svelte.dev/examples#await-blocks

Api call can fail sometimes and show error in UI as :

> Failed to generate random number. Please try again

While it does, it also prints the status code of API in console as :

[image]

Now, I am wondering is it a bad idea to show such kind of errors in UI? If so, how can I avoid showing these errors? This is something that is done by svelte I think. If we should avoid any kind of errors in console, what is the best way to write this part of code so that I could use svelte await also.

Comment: Not really a problem as long as it isn't exposing any sensitive information. A 400 error can be seen by simply opening the network tab when making a request.

Comment: don't have `<p style="color: red">{error.message}</p>` in the `:catch` - then it won't show

Answer (score -3):

This type of error is consoled by the browser itself, so you will not be able to remove it. 
You must check out for the cause because of which this error occurs.

And, Yes you should avoid showing errors and messages in the console. you should show these error in UI.

Comment: this isnt mine but would like to know why its down voted as `The 400 Bad Request error is an HTTP status code that means that the request you sent to the website server, often something simple like a request to load a web page, was somehow incorrect or corrupted and the server couldn't understand it.` will by default appear in console which is what the above user is trying to indicate.